# ImageView inside listview getting changed on search refresh

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, imageview

I have a `listview` which contains `TextView` and `ImageView`.

Here it is:

[image]

`OnClick` of `ImageView` changes opens an `alertdialog` with buttons Yes and No.

[image]

if press Yes

`imageView` changes its background to blue,

if press no,

`imageView` background  changes to red.

[image]

Till now it is working fine.

I have a search `edittext` above the `listview`, which searches based on the `textview` in the `listview`.

Now on searching, the `imageview` is not showing the changed background, but the default background only. See this:

[image]

What should I do to make the `imageview` show the image which was selected in the alert dialog.

**Code**

```
@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View v = convertView;
  if (v == null) {
   LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   v = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_lay, null);
  }else{
    v=convertView;
  }
  holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.code = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.DealerName);
  holder.btnName = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.BtnStreet); 
    holder.btnName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(final View vi) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setMessage("select any one?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



//       holder.btnName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_icon);
     vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_icon);
//     notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

      holder.btnName.setImageResource(R.drawable.blue_icon);
      //vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_icon);
//      notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
   }
  });
     v.setTag(holder);
     ViewHolder hold = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    String lb = DisplayedValues.get(position);
    hold.code.setText(getItem(position));
//   hold.btnName.setBackgroundResource(getSelectedItemPosition());

  return v;
 }
```

Comment: You need to maintain a model class to know which button was pressed. Otherwise, the listview will forget which was pressed even on scroll. Please refer to this ansewr: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27014443/2389078

Comment: please add the searching code

Comment: and store the background changes  Globally and use them while filling listview based on search criteria

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the ListView re-uses the item layouts. It inflates only as many as are visible on a screen screen at a single time. That way it saves memory.

You need to save the state of every ListView item ImageView. For example in a `boolean[]`.

The background (based on your state array) should be set in `getView` method of your adapter.

The switching **and** saving of your ImageView background state should happen in the `OnClickListener`.